# Windows 10 IoT Cordova app

Tags: windows, cordova, cross-platform, visual-studio-cordova, iot

I am trying to build and deploy cordova app on Raspberry pi 2 running windows 10 iot core. Visual Studio is set to run on Remote Machine (It automatically located the device, it is authenticated and everything). The build seems good and there isnt any errors (http://prntscr.com/8x9zl8). The raspberry pi 2 shows the splashscreen for a second and than I get this: http://prnt.sc/8x9z0m. I checked my developer licence it says its activated. I tried building Windows-AnyCPU instead of Windows-ARM, still no luck. The first time it was adding the files, now it is changing the files http://prntscr.com/8x9zh7 (I guess that is okay) but I am not able to run it.

When I try to add the .appxrecipe manually to the raspberry via the web interface it shows the following error (http://prntscr.com/8xa08k). Cordova builds AppxManifest.xml, resources.pri file and .appxrecipe and since I was able to select only one file in the web interface I added appxrecipe.

Any help would be appreciated since I dont see many questions about creating windows app for iot core using cordova.

Edit: I tried "cordova remove platform windows" and readding it again doesnt work. The project works on physcial android device/google emulator/riddle/windows app on my local machine

Answer (score 1):

After many tries I managed to fix the problem.
I needed to build the application as uap (Universal app)
"cordova build windows -- --appx=uap"

Than I manually added the appx file and the certificate via WindowsIOT user interface and it installed successfully! Now I am able to run the application without problem :)

Edit: Screenshot: http://prnt.sc/8xf9b0

Answer (score 1):

You may also add the configuration to your config.xml for cordova:

```
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
<preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="10.0" />
```

value can also be set to UAP as well.